# Can we open Design Documents directly in an IDE?

Tags: couchdb

If one wants to edit a Design Document he has to make several clicks in Fauxton (Browser-Tool) to accomplish this. Is there any faster way to edit my documents rather than loggin in into Fauxton, open the database, open the D-Doc, ..., etc.?

Or in other words: Can I open Design Documents directly in my IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the design doc in Fauxton, cut paste the json to an ide, and the cut paste back to Fauxton again.

Once you are tired of cutting and pasting every 5 minutes you can look at a couchapp tool. This is essentially a tool that cobbles together a design document across a directory structure and then inserts it to couch via the rest api.

Comment: My project is not so big, so I'll stick with the copy/paste method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a Couchapp management tool. Couchapps allow you to do many things that you probably don't ever want to touch, but one thing you can use them for is ddoc management. You create a directory structure with javascript files for maps and reducers and use the tool to push to the server.

There are many such tools available, e.g.

```
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/managing.html
http://metsonet.co.uk/situp/
```

The workflow would then look like this:

Create a local directory with the name of your design document. In this directory, create sub directories with the names of your views. In these directories create files `map.js` and `reduce.j` which you can open in your IDE, and version in `git`.

Whenever you make a change, use (say) `situp` to sync your changes (a bit like a `git push`). It will create the ddoc for you with the views in the right place and send those to the remote server.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are saying to be honest. I just use CouchDB with this Fauxton Browser-Tool. And it's too time consuming makeing a little change in a Design Document. So I came up with the idea to just open it (somehow) in my IDE. But judging from your comment that doesn't seem to be possible. Anyway, thanks for you time/post!

Comment: I've edited my answer to flesh it out a bit following your comment.

Answer (score 1):

http://ddoc.me/

Would recommend this one. It is easy to learn and very powerful. You can install it in every db if you like and let it travel with your data.